# The default export is not a React Component in page: "/" after deleting node_modules & reinstalling npm

Tags: next.js

After deleting node_modules and reinstalling npm I am still getting the error "The default export is not a React Component in page: "/" " at `http://localhost:3000/`.  When I run `npm run dev` in terminal everything goes fine until I go to `http://localhost:3000/` and get the above error.  Would anyone be able to help with this?

Had this up a running sometime last year on MacBook but now that I've returned to it I can not get next.js to work properly.  Thanks.

Here are the exact commands I used as well as files created in VS Code : [image] [image] [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: 
deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and used command npm i from hello-next folder.  Here are the errors I received : 
[image]

Comment: Did you change any code from the next template you started with? If not, can you post the exact commands you used to setup your project, as there are multiple setup guides out there

Comment: Thanks for checking in.. added the commands I used

Comment: is `index.js` inside `pages` folder?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, index.js is inside the pages folder.

Comment: @wallwalker delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then re-run `npm i`

Comment: Thanks.  I removed node_modules and package-lock.json then re-ran npm i.  Then I received errors.  Please see above screenshot.

Comment: @wallwalker `npm i` is just a shortcut of `npm install` but for some reason it doesn't work for you so just do `npm install`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes when you have not exported the component you trying to reach through the route. For example, http://localhost:3000/show in this, you need to ensure that in file "pages/show.js" you export the component. For ex.

```
export default () => {
return "Show page working ! ";
}
```

Hope it helps.