# Export default Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint

I am trying to build a next app and am receiving this error. Most the replies I see about this are around not using export default which I am doing!

I am basically trying to create a wrapper around my pages so that I can add things like a nav footer etc.

views/createView:

```
    const createView: FC = (View: FC) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <View/>
        </div>
      )
    }



export default createView;
```

pages/idx

```
import createView from 'views/createView';

const homePage: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>hi</div>
  )
}

export default createView(homePage);
```

The code works when I directly return the view but not if I do anything else.

```
const createView: FC = (View: FC) => View
```

HELP :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The default export is not a React Component in page: "/" after deleting node\_modules & reinstalling npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458831/the-default-export-is-not-a-react-component-in-page-after-deleting-node-mod)

Comment: Can you show your `/pages/index.js` page?

Answer (score 2):

Your instantiating the component and exporting it as a JSX Element, that's why you cant use it like a component because it's an instantiated value, not a function.

Shrinidhi Hegde's answer is correct, simply changing it from `<View/>` to `{View}` will solve your problem (because `<View/>` is attempting to create and render an element and `{View}` is the act of rendering a created element.).

I would strongly recommend turning your "createView" from a instantiated value to a function that creates a component as it flows nicer in React.

The example below will allow you to continue nicely by simply turning it into a function that creates an 'FC'.

```js
const CreateView = (View: FC): FC => () => (
    <div>
        <View />
    </div>
);

export default CreateView;
```

Comment: already tried this variation, still get the same error

Comment: I tested it and it worked. Create a Playground with your environment, and post it. Otherwise no one can help :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
const createView: FC = (View: FC) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {View}
        </div>
      )
    }



export default createView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, component name always be CamelCase and router/page should be small letter.
if you are using vscode then you can use this extension [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)

and short code for component is `rafce`